# In haskell why is min 8.0 8 = 8.0 and max 8.0 8 = 8.0

Tags: haskell

I'm learning haskell and I came across a weird behavior. I tried

```
Prelude> min 8.0 8
8.0
```

and

```
Prelude> max 8 8.0
8.0
```

I switch the argument positions for both functions but I got the same result. If 8.0 is returned as min shouldn't 8 be returned as max (or vice versa)? I'm using `ghci` version 8.0.2. Why does this happen?

Comment: What do you expect instead?

Comment: if 8.0 is min, then max should return 8. Or vice versa

Comment: Do you not think that 8 and 8.0 are equal?

Comment: `ghci> :t 8`
`8 :: Num a => a`

--
`ghci> :t 8.0`
`8.0 :: Fractional a => a`

--
`ghci> :t min`
`min :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`

--
`ghci> :t max`
`max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a`

Comment: if both `min a b == a` and `max a b == a`, it can be explained by `a == b`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both `8` and `8.0` represent the same `Double`, and that `Double` prints as `8.0`. This has nothing to do with `min`, per se.

```
> 8 :: Double
8.0
```

Comment: @dyukha What sounds wrong about it? What fixed version do you propose?

Comment: Shouldn't 8 represent Int? There's Int, Float and Double types in Haskell by default so 8 shouldn't represent Double

Comment: Well, I'm not into Haskell, but I expect that here 8 is not a Double, and here some conversion happens. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @dyukha You are wrong. There is no implicit conversion in Haskell, ever.

Comment: @Flameofudun `8` is a perfectly fine `Double`, as you can see by my ghci session. It's also a perfectly fine `Int`, as you say. But `8.0` is not a perfectly fine `Int`, and so `min 8 8.0` defaults to `Double` and not `Int`.

Comment: I see, thanks, I should read this: https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html ("Overloaded Literals" section especially)

Comment: without the explanation of what is `8` (and `8.0` for that matter) and why are they both treated as `Double` here, this answer is incomplete.